# How to generate custom request body from csv config data set

Tags: jmeter, preprocessor, beanshell

My requirement is to read the csv file and form the request body dynamically.

For example, my csv file will contain:

```
111
222
333
444
555
666
...
```

And my request body (post) is:

```
{
"requestHeader" : {"requestId" : "abc"},

"my-values" : [
    {"value-1" :"111"},
    {"value-1" :"222"},
    {"value-1" :"333"}
.....
],
```

Now, I have to form the request body based on counter (number of lines- this is my business requirement). For instance, if I give counter as 3, code (beanshell pre-processor) should read the first three lines from csv file, form request body and submit the request. Same way, the code should read the next three lines from csv and form the request body and submit the request.

Can you suggest how to do this?

1:

```
{
"requestHeader" : {"requestId" : "abc"},

"my-values" : [
    {"value-1" :"111"},
    {"value-1" :"222"},
    {"value-1" :"333"},
],
```

2:

```
{
   "requestHeader" : {"requestId" : "abc"},

   "my-values" : [
       {"value-1" :"444"},
       {"value-1" :"555"},
       {"value-1" :"666"},
    ],
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have put the below code in BeanShell PreProcessor